# What are the tests to measure agreement between two methods of measurement when the unit of measurement is different between the two methods?

Tags: intraclass-correlation, cohens-kappa, agreement-statistics, units, bland-altman-plot

Bland-Altman plot measure the agreement between two different methods which measures the same variable. As far as I understand Bland-Altman can measure only if the two methods have the same unit of measurement. I want to measure the agreement between two methods which measure the same variable (a continuous variable) but in different units, how can I proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by 'agreement' when the units differ?

Comment: center and scale the variables (then they are 'unitless') ?

Comment: Do the two measures evaluate the same thing? If yes it is easy.

Answer (score 2):

just factor the units to the same unit? 
eg if one is in mg/L and another in µg/L, just factor both result sets down to µg/L (simply multiply the mg/L vector by 1000) and then do the comparison. If the units are especially or fundamentally different (ie like Bq/L vs ng/fortnight or something like that!) then im not sure how you would do the comparison, and even if you did, im not sure that it would yield any meaningful result.