# Quantifying the similarity of two ordered data sets

Tags: statistical-significance, paired-data

Hi I have two data sets.

Atrue = [3.5, 8.2, 4.1, 5.5, 3.1, 4.9] and 
Aexp  = [3.2, 8.5, 3.7, 5.1, 3.3, 4.8]

Where Atrue is the theoretical data and Aexp is the experimental data.

**Each index element of Atrue corresponds to the index element of Aexp. So 3.5 would be compared to 3.2 and 8.2 would be compared to 8.5...etc.**

I want to quantify Aexp's closeness to Atrue - in particular I want to test to what statistical confidence they are similar.

What test can I use?

Note: The lists are actually much longer than the above but I just wanted to illustrate my point with an example.

Comment: Usually, statistical tests are for *differences*. What exactly do you mean by "closeness" or "similar" here? You could test for equivalence (cf, [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/85914/7290)) or agreement (cf, [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/199714/7290)).

Comment: Statisticians often use correlation, or some other [tag:association-measure]. Maybe show us a plot?