# paired T test: how to plot it?

Tags: r, paired-data, pre-post-comparison, data-visualization

What is the best way to represent a paired T test comparison for a sample with N=200 and 5 variables (only one of which is important)? nonpaired T test is not significant.

A before-after graph is too dense (too many arrows).

A normal boxplot of the differences doesn't show any significance (maybe do I have to plot it with the mean confidence intervals?).

A boxplot of both variables (before and after) doesn't show the small but significant (5% differences) effect. Same happens with kernel density graphs.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Because, by definition, a *paired* t test involves only *two* variables, please clarify what you are asking.  Could you perhaps supply a small example of the data to illustrate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, a [bivariate plot of the before/after for observations with a 1:1 line](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/images/image118.png) works well.

A [histogram of the differences](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/images/image117.png) conveys the results as well.

Answer (score 4):

*Comment:*  Perhaps the $n = 200$ differences for the one important variable can be summarized as follows:

```
summary(d)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-28.180  -2.112   4.113   3.589   9.993  29.806
sum(d > 0)
[1] 134
```

The mean and median are both about 4 > 0;  134 of the 200 observations are larger
than 0.  Let $\delta$ be the population difference, then $H_0: \delta = 0$ against $H_a: \delta \ne 0$ is rejected with a P-value < 0.0005.

A stripchart of the data shows values of each of the 200 differences (with
a few not distinguishable at the resolution of this plot). Clearly, there are more positive differences than negative ones.

```
stripchart(d, pch="|")
abline(v = 0, col="green2")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the stripchart, I will definitely use it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party but I wanted to add a more recent reference from 2017 to this thread for those like me who are looking for inspiration on how to graph paired data. The reference advocates the use of the *hybrid parallel line plot* for plotting such data.

The reference is as follows:

*Graphic Portrayal of Studies With Paired Data: A Tutorial*  by David L. Schriger, MD, MPH

and can be downloaded from this website:

https://els-jbs-prod-cdn.jbs.elsevierhealth.com/pb/assets/raw/Health%20Advance/journals/ymem/Schriger_graph2-1520020828083.pdf.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other excellent answer, it could be useful to have a *graphical* summary.  That could be a histogram of the differences, but even more useful could be a scatterplot of means aganst differences: A Tukey mean-difference plot (also called Bland-Altman plot).  For discussion and examples see [Bland-Altman (Tukey Mean-Difference) plot for differing scales](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167151/bland-altman-tukey-mean-difference-plot-for-differing-scales).  In the context of paired data we could call it a plot of *change scores* versus means.

Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%E2%80%93Altman_plot  or search this site. There is a paper dedicated to plotting paired data: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2685323?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents